# Is there any way to change disable state color of mat-slide-toggle

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want to change the `color` of disable state in `mat-slide-toggle`.

This is how slide toggle looking

[image]

This is my code

```
<div>
  <mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

How can I change `gray` bg color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root style.scss do a global style override **(Not recommended normally)** as follows. **After** you import the material theme

**Ref**: https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

....
....


.mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  background-color: #e47171 !important;
}
```

**Image Ref of style import**

[image]

Comment: I am going to write css in html file. where to add @import

Comment: Are you using a CDN ?. It normaly goes in the root **styles.scss** in the angular project

Comment: using `<link rel`  `<script src` etc

Comment: Added the image which shows where the styles need to go if you are using Angular Material module